# Get html below mouseclick via qooxdoo

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

Is threre a possibility to get the clicked link ( -tag) below the mouseclick via qooxdoo or plain JS?

Here you can see the problem: within a html-rendered table the link does not work.
http://tinyurl.com/374gzwl

Comment: seems to be a bug within QX: http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have used the qooxdoo event system for event handling than you can use the "getTarget" method form the passed event ("qx.event.type.Mouse").

But when you are added a native event handler than you can use the static method "getTarget" from "qx.bom.Event".

Please have a look at the API Viewer [1] for the details.

[1] http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/

Comment: Hi Christian. I use a qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Html within a Table. Since the migration to QX 1.2 the events for clicking on such a rendered html link the browser does not get the event and ignores the click on the link. When I use getTarget, i get a FocusIndicator. I red the api more than twice, but i did not get anything acceptable. Do you know whats wrong there?